# Zebra Striping Listbox Items XAML/C# Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, zebra-striping

I want to zebra stipe a Listbox that is generated from an observable collection of objects returned from a search.

The code is like so

```
               <ListBox x:Name="searchResultsListBox" Margin="0, 115, -12, 0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <StackPanel Width="411">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Registration}" Margin="12, -6, 12, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Margin="12, -6, 12, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Foreground="#AFA7A0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

How would I go about striping it so that the first `<stackpanel>` was yellow, the second white and the third yellow again etc etc?

Thanks,
Danny.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control which you will use inside your listbox. This will contain:
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
<Border Width="411">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Registration}" Margin="12, -6, 12, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" Foreground="White"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Margin="12, -6, 12, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Foreground="#AFA7A0"/>
</Border >
</StackPanel> 
Maintain index in the observable collection items. 
Bind the list box to the observable collection. 
Create a bordercolor property in the custom control and initialize it on the basis of index value (even/odd)